# using inline select on temporary table

Tags: mysql, sql

Iam using mysql  in a reporting tool.
I have a temporary table that Iam filling through some queries and then displaying data from the temporary table.

My table structure is

```
Prim_key    starttime             endtime          timediff
1       2012-07-20 00:00:0    2012-07-22 10:55:32   39332
2       2012-07-20 04:50:13   2012-07-22 10:55:32   158719
3       2012-07-20 10:00:00   2012-07-22 00:00:05   5
```

I need to display a table with percentage of timings < 30 , between 30-45 and > 45.
I have written the following query but i get error of **Status 1137 - Can't reopen table: 't_results'**

```
Expected result:

|   % of less than 30 min   | % of between 30 - 45 |    % of greater than 45 mins |
```

The query is

```
SELECT prim_key key, (
  SELECT count(*)*100 / (
      SELECT count(*)
      FROM t_results 
      WHERE timediff > 0 )
  FROM   t_results 
  WHERE  (timediff /60)  < 30
  ) less30, (
  SELECT count(*)*100 / (
     SELECT count(*)
     FROM t_results 
     WHERE timediff > 0 )
  FROM   t_results 
  WHERE  (timediff /60)  >=  30  and (timediff /60)  <=  45 
  ) bet3045, 
  (SELECT count(*)*100 / (
      SELECT count(*)
      FROM t_results 
     WHERE timediff > 0 ) 
  FROM t_results 
  WHERE  (timediff /60)  > 45 
 )  great45 
FROM t_results 
WHERE 1 = 1 AND 1 =1 
GROUP BY prim_key
```

Is there another way of writing it ?

Answer (score 2):

Temp tables cannot be refferred to twice within the same query.

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=10327

**EDIT**

Actually, having a little think (as you require a pivot) I believe your query will be of the form

(second edit, formatting to be in percentages)

```
SET @numRows := (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t_results WHERE timediff > 0 );
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN (timediff /60)  < 30 THEN timediff ELSE NUll END) * 100 /@numRows  less30, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN (timediff /60)  >=  30  and (timediff /60)  <=  45  THEN timediff ELSE NUll END) * 100 /@numRows bet3045, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN (timediff /60)  > 45  THEN timediff ELSE NUll END) * 100 /@numRows great45 
FROM t_results WHERE timediff > 0
```

Should do the trick. Unless I've made a rather silly mistake. Which I usually do :)

Comment: As a further point as to how to structure your query, I'd implement a case statement in your select, then group by that.

Comment: This query not give the required result. Most notably it does not return percentages. In addition, it adds a WHERE clause that is not present in the original query.

Comment: The where clause here is acutally a global version of the one present in each sub query stated in the question. Given the structure of the query, one could argue that it's rather trivial to turn the counts into percentages, (as the pivot is by far the harder part to wrap ones head around), but fair point. I shall update.

Comment: The WHERE clause in the subqueries would not affect the number of rows yielded by the main query. The WHERE clause in the main query could.

Comment: Ah yes I see your point. It appears to me however, that the total number of rows is considered to be those who have a positive time diff, thus it seems (to me at least) that it makes sense to be within the main query. 

One could even argue that the entire time_diff > 0 is rather redundant as one can hardly think of a circumstance in which the end time is earlier than the start. 

I'm sure user1606540 will clear it all up sooner or later though :)

Comment: Thank you everyone .. I have a few rows in my table with timediff = 0 . I do not want to consider these rows while calculating the %. Thus i have added the > 0 clause.

Comment: So my query is correct? Or do you require to take into acount timediff=0 in your less30? In which case I believe the percentage willbe off..

Answer (score 1):

@user1051643 is right, you can't use temp tables more than once in a query. Pity, retarded etc, but that's how it is.

That said, what are you trying to achieve with your query? What strikes me as very odd is that your main query does a GROUP BY prim_key. Assuming that prim_key is the primary key, and your query has no joins, it seems that this is redundant since the conceptual primary key of the result of a GROUP BY query is always defined exactly by the column in the GROUP BY list. I.e. your GROUP BY is redundant.

Then in your SELECT list, you do a bunch of aggregate queries on t_results, but none of them seem correlated to the current row of the main query. This means you can easily and without any loss of performance rewrite it to a series of separate queries. But more than anything else it makes me think you haven't defined the problem you want to solve precisely enough.

UPDATE:

```
select 100 * sum(
                 if (timediff < 30*60, 1, 0)
             ) / count(timediff)  
       AS "% of less than 30 min"
,      100 * sum(
                 if (timediff between 30*60 and 45*60, 1, 0)
             ) / count(timediff)  
       AS "% of between 30 - 45"
,      100 * sum(
                 if (timediff > 45*60, 1, 0)
             ) / count(timediff) 
       AS "% of greater than 45 mins"
from   t_results
```